# What's the best way to get rep with the Iron Garrison Guards?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

In Lord of the Rings Online, what's the best/easiest/quickest way to grind reputation with the Iron Garrison Guards in Moria?

For those curious: Kindred (the highest reputation status) is required with the Iron Garrison Guards in order to unlock one of your class's final legendary traits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if any of these are the BEST way, but rather than leave this question unanswered, here are the different ways I've found:

- Questing and mob-killing in Moria will generate reputation items over time, that can be traded in for reputation.
- There are a bunch of assorted quests in Moria that give IGG reputation.
- There are six crafting quest dailies at three different locations that can be used to generate a lot of crafting resources (if you're set to the right ones) as well as about 1400 Guards reputation points each. (and 700 Miner reputation points as well) That's ~8400 a day, which will take you from nothing to Kindred in a little over 10 days, without having to do anything else.
- Running the Grand Stair instance allegedly gives IGG reputation as well.